# MODIS Aerosol Data Projection

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas, modis, nasa, modis-reprojection-tool

I have been trying to work with MODIS Aerosol Products, namely MOD04_3K. For a sample HDF file from the LAADS DAAC cloud, I am extracting Latitude, Longitude and AOD data using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC

file = 'MOD04_3K.A2001001.0125.061.2017220225558.hdf'

hdf = SD(file, SDC.READ)

DATAFIELD = 'Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean'

data2D = hdf.select(DATAFIELD)

data = data2D[:,:].astype(np.double)

lat = hdf.select('Latitude')

lon = hdf.select('Longitude')

attrs = data2D.attributes(full=1)

attrs = data2D.attributes(full=1)

aoa = attrs['add_offset']
add_offset = aoa[0]

fva = attrs['_FillValue']
_FillValue = fva[0]

sfa = attrs['scale_factor']
scale_factor = sfa[0]

vra = attrs['valid_range']
valid_min = vra[0][0]        
valid_max = vra[0][1]

invalid = np.logical_or(data > valid_max,
                        data < valid_min)
invalid = np.logical_or(invalid, data == _FillValue)
data[invalid] = np.nan
data = (data - add_offset) * scale_factor
data = np.ma.masked_array(data, np.isnan(data))

lat = hdf.select('Latitude')
latitude = lat[:,:].ravel()
lon = hdf.select('Longitude')
longitude = lon[:,:].ravel()

data_dict = {
    'longitude': longitude,
    'latitude': latitude,
    'aod': np.ma.getdata(data).ravel()
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

This results in a 'nice' Pandas DataFrame with longitude, latitude, aod columns.

What I am confused about is the CRS of geolocation. According to the file specification, available [here](https://atmosphere-imager.gsfc.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/ModAtmo/MOD04_3K_CDL_006.txt), the Longitude and Latitude variables carry the characteristics noted below:

```
float Longitude(Cell_Along_Swath:mod04, Cell_Across_Swath:mod04) ;
        Longitude:valid_range = -180.f, 180.f ;
        Longitude:_FillValue = -999.f ;
        Longitude:long_name = "Geodetic Longitude" ;
        Longitude:units = "Degrees_east" ;
        Longitude:scale_factor = 1. ;
        Longitude:add_offset = 0. ;
        Longitude:Parameter_Type = "MODIS Input" ;
        Longitude:Cell_Along_Swath_Sampling = 1, 676, 3 ;
        Longitude:Cell_Across_Swath_Sampling = 1, 1354, 3 ;
        Longitude:Geolocation_Pointer = "Geolocation data not applicable" ;


float Latitude(Cell_Along_Swath:mod04, Cell_Across_Swath:mod04) ;
        Latitude:valid_range = -90.f, 90.f ;
        Latitude:_FillValue = -999.f ;
        Latitude:long_name = "Geodetic Latitude" ;
        Latitude:units = "Degrees_north" ;
        Latitude:scale_factor = 1. ;
        Latitude:add_offset = 0. ;
        Latitude:Parameter_Type = "MODIS Input" ;
        Latitude:Cell_Along_Swath_Sampling = 1, 676, 3 ;
        Latitude:Cell_Across_Swath_Sampling = 1, 1354, 3 ;
        Latitude:Geolocation_Pointer = "Geolocation data not applicable"
```

This (perhaps mistakenly) tells me that the data is already in WGS84.

If it is not, then how do I go about re-projecting them to WGS84 (EPSG:4326)?

The objective is to perform a near join to another shapefile.

The LDOPE re-projection tool available on the LAADS DAAC website appears not being maintained. If one searches for any information online, there appears a host of confusion regarding this, and each maintains their own sets of opinions about different methodologies.

This is my first time working with this product.